# Touch image to zoom fullscreen ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android

I want to create activity where there is an image that when clicked will zoom in fullscreen as examples [Zooming a View](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html)
but I use actionbarSherlock
anyone can help??

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.internal.nineoldandroids.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

public class Fragment3_4a extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
     private Animator mCurrentAnimator;
     private int mShortAnimationDuration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment3_4a);

    final View thumb1View = findViewById(R.id.thumb_button_1);
    thumb1View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            zoomImageFromThumb(thumb1View, R.drawable.logoappku);
        }
    });

    mShortAnimationDuration = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
private void zoomImageFromThumb(final View thumbView, int imageResId) {
    if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
        mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
    }

    final ImageView expandedImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.expanded_image);
    expandedImageView.setImageResource(imageResId);

    final Rect startBounds = new Rect();
    final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
    final Point globalOffset = new Point();
    thumbView.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBounds);
    findViewById(R.id.container).getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds, globalOffset);
    startBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
    finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);

    float startScale;
    if ((float) finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height()
            > (float) startBounds.width() / startBounds.height()) {
        startScale = (float) startBounds.height() / finalBounds.height();
        float startWidth = startScale * finalBounds.width();
        float deltaWidth = (startWidth - startBounds.width()) / 2;
        startBounds.left -= deltaWidth;
        startBounds.right += deltaWidth;
    } else {
        startScale = (float) startBounds.width() / finalBounds.width();
        float startHeight = startScale * finalBounds.height();
        float deltaHeight = (startHeight - startBounds.height()) / 2;
        startBounds.top -= deltaHeight;
        startBounds.bottom += deltaHeight;
    }

    thumbView.setAlpha(0f);
    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    expandedImageView.setPivotX(0f);
    expandedImageView.setPivotY(0f);

    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set
            .play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X, startBounds.left,
                    finalBounds.left))
            .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y, startBounds.top,
                    finalBounds.top))
            .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X, startScale, 1f))
            .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_Y, startScale, 1f));
    set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
    set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            mCurrentAnimator = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            mCurrentAnimator = null;
        }
    });
    set.start();
    mCurrentAnimator = set;

    final float startScaleFinal = startScale;
    expandedImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
                mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
            }

            AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
            set
                    .play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X, startBounds.left))
                    .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y, startBounds.top))
                    .with(ObjectAnimator
                            .ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X, startScaleFinal))
                    .with(ObjectAnimator
                            .ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_Y, startScaleFinal));
            set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
            set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mCurrentAnimator = null;
                }

                @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                        thumbView.setAlpha(1f);
                        expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mCurrentAnimator = null;
                    }
                });
                set.start();
                mCurrentAnimator = set;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click your image do something like this, it will hide status bar and actionbar:

```
getSupportActionbar().hide() // hide actionbar obviously

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
   getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
} else {
   View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
   // Hide the status bar.
   int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
   decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```